# SQL Server Error: 18456 (Windows and SQL Authentication)

Tags: sql-server

I'm already done with our capstone defense last Oct. 24, 2018 and no error occurred. Then my friend asked me today for help using SQL Server. I logon to my SQL Server Management Studio and ***BOOM***, I can't login suddenly. My default login is `KENNETH\SQLEXPRESS` (using Windows authentication) as the admin or local. I can't also login with the account I made before with `MyUserName` as username and `mypassword` as password (SQL Server authentication). In short, I'm locked out.

I opened my `SQLAGENT.OUT` file using notepad and this what showed:

```
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ? [000] Event Global\sqlserverRecComplete$SQLEXPRESS opened
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 14.0.1000.169 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 13844
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is WORKGROUP\KENNETH$.
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 18456, Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\KENNETH$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] 
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 0). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server 'KENNETH\SQLEXPRESS'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 18456, Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\KENNETH$'. [SQLSTATE 28000] 
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ! [382] Logon to server 'KENNETH\SQLEXPRESS' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
2018-11-06 22:48:02 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

Even though I'm already done using this, can still someone help me?

Comment: You need the SQL Server log file (`ERRORLOG` in the instance directory), which contains the detailed error state. Error 18456 has many [different causes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29613/login-failed-for-user-error-18456-severity-14-state-38).

Comment: Detailed error is showing one common error: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Sql Server Agent cannot run with SQL Express. I think that's what the log is showing

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

If this message is caused by `SQL Agent Job` connection then we will need to check the source `SQL server agent service account` name from Server manager or `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

> **In Services -> Go to the SQL Server Agent Service  –> properties  –>  Check the logon tab where we can find the account name.**

Step 2:

Now check and add the login we found above or if the its caused by `ODBC Data Source SQL Server Connection` then add the Login used in `ODBC` to the `SQL server instance`.

> **By checking in Security tab –> logins with necessary permission on your target machine where its trying to connect or run the job on.**

This can be same instance or different instance on same or some other server.